# How to reset vertical scroll after ViewPager fragment swiped out?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` in my project that contains some articles loading from database.

According to length of each article, user has to scroll down a `ScrollView` inside fragment layout to read that.

When user swipes to next fragment (article) then comes back to previous fragment (article), it shows the article in last vertical scroll position it was left; but I need to reset vertical scroll position to top when a fragment swiped out.

I tried `OnPageChangeListener()` methods to handle it but I failed, because for example `onPageScrolled` resets scroll once user starts swiping, while I need it happen after (previous) fragment swiped out.

How can I do it?

Comment: u need to reset position in fragment. Try to add scrolltoPosition(1); inside your fragment.

Comment: @Divyesh in which method? `onCreateView`?

Comment: post your frAGMENT CODE.

Comment: in your `onTabSelected` method set `scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0,0);`

Answer (score 0):

override `setUserVisibleHint` method in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
   if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
       scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
   }
}
```

Comment: how to define `scrollview`? `ScrollView scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.articleScrollView );` doesn't work inside the method!

Comment: define it in onCreate method, just like other views